# Is there a way to export iPhone slideshow to PC?

Tags: iphone, photos

I’m using an iPhone 5s and windows computer.

I’d like to watch and share the beautiful slideshow iPhone creates with Photos.
[image: That's what I want]

Comment: What do you mean by 'slideshow'?  Do you mean a 'Memories' on the 'For You' tab in Photos?

Comment: When you select some pictures in Photos click share then there is the option shown as a play button which creates a slideshow.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard people use the same name for Memories.  I don't believe there's any way to export the slideshow in iOS.  You can do it on the Mac.

Comment: Do you mean that if I had a Mac I could export it to a PC as well?

Comment: I believe you can by exporting it first to iTunes and then to any other device.  I'm not by my Mac right now so I can't say for sure this works but I remember something similar to this.  Hopefully, someone can answer your question about iOS and then you don't need the Mac.

Answer (score -1):

If you really really want it you can try a third-party app called, [CoolPixel](https://iosninja.io/ipa-library/download-coolpixel-ipa-ios-iphone-ipad). It will let you record the slideshow as it plays. However, I am not sure of any issues that may arise from using it. (It's not in the App Store yet), but I have used it for a year now and I haven't noticed anything wrong with it. Try it at your own risk, though.